# Поиск и удаление уникальных значений в векторе по определенному полю кортежа

Tags: c++, алгоритм, vector, tuple, delete

С++ Есть вектор кортежей типа

```
std::vector <tuple< ULONG, ULONG, ULONG, time_t, wstring, int >> drv;
std::vector <drvToTuple> drv;
```

сначала его сортирую

```
bool sortbyPath(const tuple<ULONG, ULONG, ULONG, time_t, wstring, int>& a,
    const tuple<ULONG, ULONG, ULONG, time_t, wstring, int>& b)
{
    return (get<4>(a) < get<4>(b));
}

sort(drv.begin(), drv.end(), sortbyPath);
```

Подскажите как удалить уникальные значения основываясь на 4 поле (wstring) кортежа?

```
2056, 2328, 94, 1545877351, L"Sasha", 15
2057, 2328, 94, 1545877351, L"Masha", 15
2057, 2328, 94, 1545877353, L"Dasha", 15
2058, 2328, 94, 1545877353, L"Sasha", 15
2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354, L"Misha", 15
2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354, L"Misha", 15
```

в итоге должно остаться

```
2056, 2328, 94, 1545877351, L"Sasha", 15
2057, 2328, 94, 1545877351, L"Masha", 15
2057, 2328, 94, 1545877353, L"Dasha", 15
2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354, L"Misha", 15
```

Comment: Вы хотели сказать, как оставить уникальные значения и удалить дублирующиеся значения?  Для этого существует стандартный алгоритм std::unique

Comment: Зачем вы начали с рассказа о какой-то сортировке, если в ваших примерах ничего не отсортировано? Является ли сохранение исходного порядка элементов требованием задачи?

Comment: Ну хотя бы за тем, что std::unique удаляет соседние элементы, и что бы с ее помощью удалить все дубликаты, надо сначала отсортировать. Далее следует вопрос, который я задал выше.  Исходный порядок не важен.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [`std::unique()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) и бинарный предикат, использующий вашу функцию `sortbyPath()`:

```
template< class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIt, class BinaryPredicate >
ForwardIt unique( ExecutionPolicy&& policy, ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, BinaryPredicate p );
```

код в итоге может быть примерно таким:

```
std::sort( drv.begin(), drv.end(), sortbyPath );
auto it = std::unique( drv.begin(), drv.end(), []( const auto &a, const auto &b ) {
     return not sortbyPath( a, b ) and not sortByPath( b, a ); 
} );
drv.erase( it, drv.end() );
```

либо можно написать еще одну функцию `equalByPath()`, что породит дублирование кода, но будет скорее всего более эффективным.

Если вы сортируете только для того, чтобы оставить уникальные, то это делать не обязательно, проще использовать [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) и [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
std::unordered_set<std::wstring> uset; // тут была ошибка unoredered_set вместо unordered_set
auto it = std::remove_if( drv.begin(), drv.end(), [&uset]( const auto &d ) {
    return not uset.insert( std::get<4>( d ) ).second;
} );
drv.erase( it, drv.end() );
```

Comment: Можно намного проще заполнять множество с такими же типами данных из вектора  и копировать в вектор(если нужно)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan намного проще, чем что?

Comment: чем выполнять  std::remove_if и   drv.erase

Comment: Понял, под множеством имелось в виду `std::set`. Тут есть нюансы. Код будет проще, но цена будет высокой. Во первых копирование всего кортежа, во вторых реализовать `std::unordered_set` по этому кортежу будет несколько нетривиально. Поэтому либо цена будет еще выше если использовать `std::set`, либо код будет не сильно проще, если не сложнее.

Comment: копирование из вектора в set намного проще и дишевле, чем  перетаскивание элементов вектора по нетривиальному предикату, с последующим удалением. А код  вовсе и не нужен, а нужно одной строчкой обьявлять такой  set<type> uset(drv.begin(), drv.end())

Comment: "копирование из вектора в set намного проще и дишевле, чем перетаскивание элементов вектора по нетривиальному предикату, с последующим удалением." такие заявления желательно подтверждать. Насчет `set<type> uset(drv.begin(), drv.end())` может лучше подумать сначала?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать комбинацию метода вектора `erase` со стандартным алгоритмом `std::unique`. (Если вы хотите поместить результат в другой вектор или контейнер, то можно использовать алгоритм `std::unique_copy`).

Например,

```
drv.erase( std::unique( std::begin( drv ), std::end( drv ), 
           []( const auto &a, const auto &b )
           {
               return std::get<4>( a ) == std::get<4>( b );
           } ), std::end( drv ) );
```

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

typedef unsigned long ULONG;

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<ULONG, ULONG, ULONG, time_t, std::wstring, int>> drv =
    {
        { 056,  2328, 94, 1545877351, L"Sasha", 15 },
        { 2057, 2328, 94, 1545877351, L"Masha", 15 },
        { 2057, 2328, 94, 1545877353, L"Dasha", 15 },
        { 2058, 2328, 94, 1545877353, L"Sasha", 15 },
        { 2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354, L"Misha", 15 },
        { 2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354, L"Misha", 15 }
    };

    for ( const auto &item : drv )
    {
        std::wcout << std::setw( 4 ) << std::get<0>( item ) << ", " 
                   << std::setw( 4 ) << std::get<1>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::setw( 2 ) << std::get<2>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::get<3>( item ) << ". "
                   << std::get<4>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::get<5>( item ) << '\n';
    }       

    std::wcout << '\n';

    std::sort( std::begin( drv ), 
               std::end( drv ),
               []( const auto &a, const auto &b ) 
               { 
                    return std::get<4>( a ) < std::get<4>( b ); 
               } );

    drv.erase( std::unique( std::begin( drv ), 
               std::end( drv ),
               []( const auto &a, const auto &b )
               {
                    return std::get<4>( a ) == std::get<4>( b );
               } ), std::end( drv ) );


    for ( const auto &item : drv )
    {
        std::wcout << std::setw( 4 ) << std::get<0>( item ) << ", " 
                   << std::setw( 4 ) << std::get<1>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::setw( 2 ) << std::get<2>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::get<3>( item ) << ". "
                   << std::get<4>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::get<5>( item ) << '\n';
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
  46, 2328, 94, 1545877351. Sasha, 15
2057, 2328, 94, 1545877351. Masha, 15
2057, 2328, 94, 1545877353. Dasha, 15
2058, 2328, 94, 1545877353. Sasha, 15
2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354. Misha, 15
2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354. Misha, 15

2057, 2328, 94, 1545877353. Dasha, 15
2057, 2328, 94, 1545877351. Masha, 15
2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354. Misha, 15
  46, 2328, 94, 1545877351. Sasha, 15
```

С другой стороны, возможно вам сразу же следовало избрать другой контейнер, как, например, `std::set` или `std::unordered_set`.

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как можно выбрать только уникальные элементы исходного вектора во множество `std::set` без изменения самого вектора.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

typedef unsigned long ULONG;

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<ULONG, ULONG, ULONG, time_t, std::wstring, int>> drv =
    {
        { 056,  2328, 94, 1545877351, L"Sasha", 15 },
        { 2057, 2328, 94, 1545877351, L"Masha", 15 },
        { 2057, 2328, 94, 1545877353, L"Dasha", 15 },
        { 2058, 2328, 94, 1545877353, L"Sasha", 15 },
        { 2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354, L"Misha", 15 },
        { 2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354, L"Misha", 15 }
    };

    for ( const auto &item : drv )
    {
        std::wcout << std::setw( 4 ) << std::get<0>( item ) << ", " 
                   << std::setw( 4 ) << std::get<1>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::setw( 2 ) << std::get<2>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::get<3>( item ) << ". "
                   << std::get<4>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::get<5>( item ) << '\n';
    }       

    std::wcout << '\n';

    auto cmp = []( const auto &a, const auto &b ) 
               { 
                    return std::get<4>( a ) < std::get<4>( b ); 
               };

    std::set<std::tuple<ULONG, ULONG, ULONG, time_t, std::wstring, int>, 
             decltype( cmp )> tuple_set( cmp );

    tuple_set.insert( std::begin( drv ), std::end( drv ) );              

    for ( const auto &item : tuple_set )
    {
        std::wcout << std::setw( 4 ) << std::get<0>( item ) << ", " 
                   << std::setw( 4 ) << std::get<1>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::setw( 2 ) << std::get<2>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::get<3>( item ) << ". "
                   << std::get<4>( item ) << ", "
                   << std::get<5>( item ) << '\n';
    }       

    std::wcout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
  46, 2328, 94, 1545877351. Sasha, 15
2057, 2328, 94, 1545877351. Masha, 15
2057, 2328, 94, 1545877353. Dasha, 15
2058, 2328, 94, 1545877353. Sasha, 15
2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354. Misha, 15
2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354. Misha, 15

2057, 2328, 94, 1545877353. Dasha, 15
2057, 2328, 94, 1545877351. Masha, 15
2059, 2328, 94, 1545877354. Misha, 15
  46, 2328, 94, 1545877351. Sasha, 15
```